# TS2339: Property 'xxxx' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: typescript

Meet this issue when I operate the DOM elements in Typescript.

I tried the most answered way on stackoverflow:

```
let ele: HTMLImageElement = document.getElementById("img") as HTMLImageElement
```

But still get the error message when compile:

[image]

Not sure why? Is my Typescript configuration wrong?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

Project code here: https://github.com/mashirozx/sakura2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably the issue (from your `webpack.config.js`):

```
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'ts-loader' },
          { 
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript'],
            },
          },
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
```

Typically, you'd use *either* ts-loader *or* babel-loader, not both. I note that removing either one of them from your project allows your code to run as you'd expect. Note that you can still use both together, but you'd want to take the TypeScript preset out of your Babel config I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a good idea, but I found `xxx['xxx']` works:

```
let ele: HTMLImageElement = document.getElementById("cover-img") as HTMLImageElement
let eleW: number = ele['naturalWidth']
console.log(eleW)
```

Comment: The array notation you're using is the weakly-typed version of object's dot notation. 
So you're basically bypassing typescript by using the array notation.